# Is there any image comparison server software out there, made from something like OpenCV (Windows or Mac)?

Tags: windows, macos, image-processing, opencv

Is there any image comparison server software out there, made from something like OpenCV (Windows or Mac)? I'm looking to make an in-house image recognition server for an internal project and I need to know if there are any options out there.

Most that I see available are Internet web-based API's and cost monthly fees. I'd like to set something up internally instead, both for quicker speeds and cheaper costs.

If not, what is recommended as the best way to set something like this up?

Comment: You could create a webapp with Django and the openCV python bindings.

Comment: You could mod the sample scripts in opencv/samples which use feature matching to check if two passed images are similar. You could then use that script to give you yes/no inside a django/flask app as an api endpoint.

Link of find_obj.py: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/find_obj.py

Pro tip: For faster matching almost as accurate as SURF/SIFT, use ORB.

Comment: Or you could also have googled it: http://goo.gl/jzda9F

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

http://www.abbyy.com/recognition_server/product_overview/ **-** [Product Overview](http://www.abbyy.com/recognition_server/product_overview/)
http://www.cvisiontech.com/products/general/maestro-recognition-server.html

Also this article might be helpful

[https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=6096210+10692120271328191677&pli=1](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=6096210%2010692120271328191677&pli=1)

Comment: Yeah I already looked at both of those... probably a bit too expensive and complicated for what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

We have included a binary image classifier with the open library SimpleCV:
http://www.simplecv.org

Here is a video of what I'm talking about:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cH5e-ZkJa0U

You could use that example to start to build something up. It doesn't work as an image search out of the box, but you could probably easily modify it to do what you want.